# htaccess rewrite rule with strings that contain slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mod rewrite rule like the following.

```
RewriteRule ^bands/([^/]*)$ /folder/index.php?palabra=$1 [L]
```

It works except when someone access a link that uses a word with a / symbol on the band name, for example the band ac/dc would not work and shows a 404 error.
Im guessing some kind of problem with the regex.
How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^bands/([^/]+)/?$ /folder/index.php?palabra=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava Sadly it didnt work, still 404.

Comment: `[^/]` is a negated character class, allowing _anything but_ a /. If you don't want to exclude any characters in particular, then simply make that a `.`instead, `^bands/(.*)` (Anchoring the pattern at the end with `$` doesn't achieve anything in that case anyway, so it can be removed.)